# ¿Puede una oración final aparecer al inicio de una frase?

Tags: sintaxis

Me gustaría preguntar a los hablantes nativos si una oración final puede aparecer al inicio de una frase, p. ej.:

> (1) ***Para que no te pierdas en la calle***, toma este mapa.
>   (2) ***Para que nadie me viera***, escapé por un callejón cercano.

¿Es común? ¿O preferiríais el orden: oración principal + oración subordinada?

Comment: Tus dos ejemplos son correctos y esa estructura es de uso común.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, se puede alterar el orden normal.  Por lo general, se hace para agregar énfasis, o en ciertas ocasiones, por estética.  Yo lo he encontrado en comunicación oral o poesía.

En tus ejemplos, nota que al explicar la razón para el acto, motivas a tu audiencia.  A veces es útil hacerlo así para educar, por ejemplo. (Para que puedas jugar, ¡haz la tarea!)

Comment: Gracias Carlos Alejo, necesito practicar mi ¡castellano!